# How to get Enzyme type() of null instead of function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm new to *unit-testing* and ran into a problem. I can't get *Enzyme* to return null for my Element which has an if statement `!item => null`.
  How to check if element is null if no '*item prop*' given?

```
 it("should not render without `props.item`", () => {
    wrapper.setProps({
      item: null,
    })

    console.log(wrapper.find('ThemeTile').childAt(0).name()) // === 'Link'
    expect(wrapper.find('ThemeTile').childAt(0).type()).toEqual(null);

    // returns expect(received).toEqual(expected)
    // Expected value to equal:
    //    null
    //Received:
    //   [Function Link]
  })
```

And this is the relevant render method of the ThemeTile.

```
render() {
    const { classes, item, href } = this.props;

    if(!item) {
      return null;
    }

    const image                   = buildImageUrl(item, 'square', 300, 300);

    return (
      <Link to={href} className={classes.root}>
        <div className={classes.imageContainer}>
          <div className={classes.image} style={{backgroundImage: `url(${image})`}} />
        </div>
        <Typography className={classes.title}>
          {this.props.item.title}
        </Typography>
      </Link>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities to check if enzyme wrapper renders nothing. The following looks quite clean to me:

```
expect(wrapper.getElement()).toBe(null);
```

See [this thread](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/52) for a discussion about this.